# How to port this VB.net / C# code to Objective-C / iOS?

Tags: c#, objective-c, vb.net, ios, math

I need to do this in Objective-C / iOS:

```
Math.Round(h, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

I know we have a round() function, but how about that "AwayFromZero" option? What is the equivalent to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [ceil](http://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/objective-c-math/)

```
ceil(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a ceil / ceiling function in Objective-C / iOS? It would have the same effect as your vb/c# code.